# Apache redirects to default homepage

Tags: apache2, php, dns

I have two servers running the same application using apache webserver on an ubuntu os.
**server 1: x.com**, **server 2: x.y.com**

Initially, those applications were running fine. Due to some changes, we adjusted to below

**server 1: x.y.com**, **server 2:  x.com**

After the DNS change, server 1 and server 2 just displays the default apache page. when I test by setting the local IP address in the host file, everything loads fine but using the DNS record, the default webpages loads up

below is my configuration

HTTP to https

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName <x.com> <x.y.com>
        ServerAlias <x> 
        ErrorLog error log
    
        Redirect / https://<x.com><x.y.com>
</VirtualHost>
```

Https Config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName <x.com> <x.y.com>
        ServerAlias <x> <y>
        ErrorLog error location

        DocumentRoot /apps/main/public/
    <Directory /apps/main/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
        require all granted
        </Directory>
        
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/SSL_cert/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/SSL_cert/cert.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/SSL_cert/IntermediateCA.crt

    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES:!CAMELLIA
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    #SSLUseStapling on
</VirtualHost>
```

the error log is clean too.

Comment: You've provided no release details of your server. Standard or Core server installs?

Comment: Going off the info you’ve provided, your `ServerAlias` values need to be updated to include a catch-all. Add `*.*` and `*.*.*` to the end of the alias to ensure that all unrecognized traffic is sent to the primary Apache root directory. From there your application can determine if a redirect is necessary 

Comment: So, i've been able to fix it by reverting to the 000-default.conf and building from there. But another issue was encontered when i used the  ```Redirect / https://x.com``` in the virtualhost